# Create time-lapse gif centering point of interest

Tags: webvideos, time-lapse

My wife is currently very pregnant and I have taken a photo every week of her bump. I now want to make a gif or something similar showing the bump growing. I used the first free gif maker I found (gifmaker.me) and realised that I need to somehow make the bump the centre of the image for each frame of the gif for it to look really good. I figure I need to edit/crop the images somehow.

Any ideas out there how best to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessary need to make it the center of the image but always appear at the exact same point in the frame. The center is usually an easy referencing point for that purpose, so why not use that.

Obviously the easiest would be to make the photographs in a way that they don't need postpcessing. If this chance has passed already, you can get a (free) image editing software like the "gimp" and move & scale alle pictures in a way that they have approx the same size and center.

BTW good luck with the baby, ours is almost 3 months already and it has been quite some experience so far.

Comment: thanks for the answer - I've done a lazy version using Gimp, so thanks for the pointer in that direction. My gif definitely looks better than before!

Comment: and apparently Return sends the response....